# Application users in row-level policies: how to set session variables

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, jooq, row-level-security

I am trying to write row-level policies which check user rights before executing queries. In this context, I need to be able to set a session variable, containing the user identifier, when a connection is fetched from the connection pool and unset/release that same session variable when the connection is given back to the pool. The following blog might give a good background to explain what I am trying to do: https://blog.2ndquadrant.com/application-users-vs-row-level-security/

In my setup, I have the following layers:

1. Hikari: `HikariDataSource`
2. Spring: `TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy` (using Hikari data source), `DataSourceTransactionManager` (using Hikary data source)
3. jOOQ: `DataSourceConnectionProvider` (using Spring data source), `DefaultDSLContext`

The first two layers are internal only. That is, all queries in the application are done via jOOQ, the final layer.

So, I need to be able to implement a callback on connection `take from pool` and `give back to pool`.

I have been looking through documentation of Hikari and Spring, but couldn't find anything useful. This is probably my first question: does Hikari and/or Spring provide such callbacks?

The next step in my investigation was jOOQ. I stumbled upon `ExecuteListener`. This is my follow-up question: would `ExecuteListener` be a good application for this? This does not implement the actual point when connection is taken and given back, but an `execution context` is probably good enough in my case (as all my queries are done in jOOQ)? If so, should I implement the `start` and `end` functions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be solved at various levels in your current stack. Here are two suggestions:

#### Solving this in a `DataSource` / `Connection` proxy

Most connection pools implement the following semantics:

- [`DataSource.getConnection()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/sql/DataSource.html#getConnection--): "Take from pool"
- [`Connection.close()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html): "Give back to pool"

So, you could proxy those two APIs and implement your desired semantics inside of those relevant methods. This is a bit more work, but it will work with any JDBC client, including jOOQ (i.e. it will also work when you do not use jOOQ)

#### Solving this in jOOQ

If all your database interactions go through jOOQ, you can solve this more easily with jOOQ directly, using the [`ConnectionProvider` SPI](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/ConnectionProvider.html), which contains two methods that have exactly the semantics you require:

- [`ConnectionProvider.acquire()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/ConnectionProvider.html#acquire--)
- [`ConnectionProvider.release(Connection)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/ConnectionProvider.html#release-java.sql.Connection-)

So, instead of using jOOQ's out-of-the-box [`DataSourceConnectionProvider`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/impl/DataSourceConnectionProvider.html), you could do this:

```java
public class MyConnectionProvider implements ConnectionProvider {

    // Configure spring to inject your data source here
    @Autowire
    DataSource ds;

    @Override
    public Connection acquire() {
        try {
            Connection c = ds.getConnection();
            // Do your stuff here
            return c;
        }
        catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new DataAccessException("Something failed", e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void release(Connection c) {
        try {
            // Do your stuff here
            c.close();
        }
        catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new DataAccessException("Something failed", e);
        }
    }
}
```

You could do this with `ExecuteListener`, too, but the above approach is certainly simpler.

Comment: Thank you. I did not realize that the `take` and `give back` functionalities are simply two functions. I'll either proxy them in the `DataSource` or use the `ConnectionProvider` in jOOQ!